# How to get HTMLElements in slots using vue3?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

Things happened when I try to develop a Layer component. Here's the code:

*// Wrapper.vue*

```
<template>
  <slot v-bind="attrs"></slot>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import {
  defineProps,
  ref,
  watch,
  useAttrs,
  onMounted,
  onUnmounted,
  getCurrentInstance,
} from "vue";

const props = defineProps({
  name: { type: String, default: "" },
  zIndex: { type: Number, default: 0 },
});
const attrs = useAttrs();
const inst = getCurrentInstance();

const observer = ref<MutationObserver | null>(null);

watch(
  () => [props.zIndex, props.name],
  () => {
    setBrothersAttrs();
  }
);

onMounted(() => {
  let el = inst?.vnode.el;
  if (el) {
    if (!observer.value)
      observer.value = new MutationObserver(setBrothersAttrs);
    observer.value.observe(el.parentElement, { childList: true });
  }
  setBrothersAttrs();
});

onUnmounted(() => {
  if (observer.value) observer.value.disconnect();
});

const setBrothersAttrs = () => {
  let el = inst?.vnode.el;
  let children = el?.parentElement?.children;
  if (el && children) {
    for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
      let bro = children[i];
      if (bro === el) continue;
      bro.style.zIndex = props.zIndex;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

*// Test.vue*

```
<template>
  <div class="test">
    <Wrapper name="wrapper1" :z-index="1">
      <img class="picture1" />
      <div class="inner">
        <Wrapper name="wrapper2" :z-index="2">
          <img class="picture2" />
        </Wrapper>
      </div>
      <Wrapper name="wrapper3" :z-index="3">
        <img class="picture3" />
      </Wrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import Wrapper from "./Wrapper.vue";
</script>
```

*// Result in HTML:*

```
<div class="test">
  <img class="picture1" style="z-index: 1" /><!-- if no wrapper3, "z-index: 3" -->
  <div class="inner" style="z-index: 1">
    <img class="picture2" style="z-index: 2" />
  </div>
  <img class="picture3" style="z-index: 1" /><!-- if no wrapper3, "z-index: 3" -->
</div>
```

> As the code above, the component Wrapper is an empty component. Its purpose is to set the z-index of HTMLElements in slot["default"].

Unfortunately I can't find children elements in useSlots()["default"]. **So I try to let a mutation observer to observe the parent's childList.**

It works fine alone (*like picture1 and picture2 in the example*). **But it override each other when multiple Wrappers wrap together (*like picture3 in the example, picture3's z-index seted by wrapper3 is overrided by wrapper1*).** That means they share a same parent so that the children of the parent always be the same.

So the problem is becomed "**How to get HTMLElements in slots**" again now... Can any vuejs master help me out ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be done much simpler using Vue Render Functions: [Rendering Slots](https://vuejs.org/guide/extras/render-function.html#rendering-slots)

```js
const { createApp, h } = Vue;

const Wrapper = {
  props:  {
    name: { type: String, default: "" },
    zIndex: { type: Number, default: 0 },
  },
  setup(props, { slots }) {
    let children = slots.default();
    if (children) {
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        children[i].props.style = `z-index: ${props.zIndex}`;
      }
    }  
    return () => slots.default()
  }
}

const App = { 
  components:  { Wrapper }
}

const app = createApp(App)
const vm = app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 2; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
   <div class="test">
   Test
    <Wrapper name="wrapper1" :z-index="1">
      <img class="picture1" />
      <div class="inner">
        <Wrapper name="wrapper2" :z-index="2">
          <img class="picture2" />
        </Wrapper>
      </div>
      <Wrapper name="wrapper3" :z-index="3">
        <img class="picture3" />
      </Wrapper>
    </Wrapper>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. ```h('div', slots.default())``` This code creates a div element witch is not matching my need. I don't want to create any element as children's parent but change children's attr sliently. Could this be possible?

Comment: You don't really need the `div`. I have updated the playground.